# find closest match within a vector to fill missing values using dplyr

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, nearest-neighbor

A dummy dataset is :

```
data <- data.frame(
  group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2),
  dates = as.Date(c("2005-01-01", "2006-05-01", "2007-05-01","2004-08-01",
            "2005-03-01","2010-02-01")),
  value = c(10,20,NA,40,NA,5)
)
```

For each `group`, the missing values need to be filled with the non-missing value corresponding to the nearest date within same group. In case of a tie, pick any.

I am using `dplyr`. `which.closest` from birk but it needs a vector and a value. How to look up within a vector without writing loops. Even if there is an `SQL` solution, will do.
Any pointers to the solution?

May be something like: `value = value[match(which.closest(dates,THISdate) & !is.na(value))]` 
Not sure how to specify `Thisdate`.

Edit: The expected value vector should look like:

```
value = c(10,20,20,40,10,5)
```

Comment: Can you also show us the expected output of `value`, after replacing the `NA` values?  What does nearest date mean here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: just edited, the dates and expected value

Comment: I can't think of a straightforward SQL query which would help here (and you never even told us which database you would be using).  Maybe you will get an R solution here.

Comment: You can `arrange` by `date` and use `na.locf`, `library(dplyr);
library(zoo);
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(dates) %>%
  mutate(value = na.locf(value))`

Comment: I don't think knowing the backend database will help. It is SQL server otherwise. But if I get an SQL solution,  will use `sqldf` to run SQL query on this data frame

Comment: @RonakShah, I think it will fill with  only the prior date. If I add a row `<1,"2005-04-01",15>`, it wont pick 01/04/2005 as the closest month to 01/03/2005.

Comment: `tidyr::fill` is a tidyverse version of `zoo::na.locf`. You can set the direction in both.

Comment: @alistaire, I ownt have prior information about direction. I need to pick the nearest date with non-NA value

Comment: @Kaur I tend to believe the answers given do satisfy the question asked. Hope you look into them

Answer (score 2):

Using `knn1` (nearest neighbor) from the class package (which comes with R -- don't need to install it) and dplyr define an `na.knn1` function which replaces each NA value in `x` with the non-NA `x` value having the closest `time`.

```
library(class)

na.knn1 <- function(x, time) {
   is_na <- is.na(x)
   if (sum(is_na) == 0 || all(is_na)) return(x)
   train <- matrix(time[!is_na])
   test <- matrix(time[is_na])
   cl <- x[!is_na]
   x[is_na] <- as.numeric(as.character(knn1(train, test, cl)))
   x
}

data %>% mutate(value = na.knn1(value, dates))
```

giving:

```
  group      dates value
1     1 2005-01-01    10
2     1 2006-05-01    20
3     1 2007-05-01    20
4     1 2004-08-01    40
5     1 2005-03-01    10
6     2 2010-02-01     5
```

Add an appropriate `group_by` if the intention was to do this by group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the use of `sapply` to find the values closest since the `x` argument in `which.closest only takes a single value.

first create a `vect` whereby the dates with no values are replaced with `NA` and use it within the `which.closest` function.

```
library(birk)
vect=replace(data$dates,which(is.na(data$value)),NA)
transform(data,value=value[sapply(dates,which.closest,vec=vect)])
  group      dates value
1     1 2005-01-01    10
2     1 2006-05-01    20
3     1 2007-05-01    20
4     1 2004-08-01    40
5     1 2005-03-01    10
6     2 2010-02-01     5
```

if `which.closest` was to take a vector then there would be no need of `sapply`. But this is not the case.
Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(birk)
library(dplyr)
data%>%mutate(vect=`is.na<-`(dates,is.na(value)),
              value=value[sapply(dates,which.closest,vect)])%>%
     select(-vect)
```